# Converting string date from one timezone to UTC in Datastage

Tags: c, datetime, datastage

I would like to convert dates I receive from timezone 'Europe/Warsaw' to UTC. I have tried to find suitable libraries in C to create a Datastage routine. I did not find anything that would allow to flexibly change the source timezone keeping in mind the change from summer to winter time (daylight). Another way is to use a database function, e.g. in DB2, but currently I am trying to solve the problem without creating stored procedures. Anyone solved a similar problem?

I get the input date in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS',
Input Timezone = 'Europe/Warsaw',
Output Timezone = 'UTC'.

I would like to create a solution that would allow me to swap e.g. Input Zone, something passed by parameter e.g. 'Europe/London'. I cannot rely on the system time unfortunately.